# Trouble with split alignment in equations

Tags: alignment, split

I have a trouble with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a&=b+c\\&
\begin{split}
=c+d+e&\qquad\text{this is}\\
=f+g&\qquad\text{this is}\\
=h.
\end{split}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a&=b+c\qquad\text{this is}\\
&=f+g\qquad\text{this is}\\
&=h.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

My problem is this: In first equation the =-signs are not left-aligned, and I'd like to have something like the second equation, keeping `\text{this is}` in the same alignment of last equation.
I hope my question is clear.
Thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: Do you believe you can nest `split` inside `split`? Well, unbelieve it.

Comment: @egreg Doesn't exist a solution for my problem? If the answer is negative, how could I solv my problem?, this is, does exist a sort of split-alignment that uses two & in the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get no error from nesting `split` inside `split`, but no good output either.

You can use `alignedat` instead of `split`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
a &= b+c\\
  &= c+d+e &\qquad& \text{this is} \\
  &= f+g   &&       \text{this is} \\
  &= h.
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Or, more simply, `aligned`.

[image]